# Assigning a function from another class to an event handler

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Consider the following situation. I have 4 classes in different cs files:

```
class0.cs
class1.cs
class2.cs
class3.cs
```

I want the last 3 classes to be fixed(use them in a dll) and only change the class0 from where I use the dll.

So in class0 I want to define a function that will be executed when an event occurs. For example:

```
public void callStart(Object x, EventArg e){...}
```

This event should be responded by an object of class3. There is a relashionship between this classes.

```
class0 use an instance of class1
class1 use an instance of class2
class2 use an instance of class3
```

So my plan is pass the function callStart as a parameter of the constructor so   it can reach the object of class3:

So the constructor of each class is something like this:

```
public class1(...., Func<Object,EventArg> callStart){
...
c2 = new class2(..., callStart);
}

public class2(...., Func<Object,EventArg> callStart){
...
c3 = new class3(..., callStart);
}

public class3(...., Func<Object,EventArg> callStart){...

OnCall += callStart;
}
```

The compiler in Visual Studio 2015 tell me that an `Func<Object,EventArg>` can't be turned into an `EventHandler<EventArg>`, but I can assign a public void function to the EventHandler  if I define it directly in class3.cs.

I apologize if my description of the problem is confusing. I feel that my brain cells are entangled.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Why not just use `EventHandler<EventArgs>` as the parameter type? _but I can assign a public void function"_ -- For delegate value assignments, the types have to match exactly, but when using the implicit method-group-to-delegate-type conversion, as long as the method signature matches, the compiler will automatically generate the right delegate type instance for you. Note that if you can't replace the type in the method parameter list, you can change the event subscription to `OnCall += (sender, e) => callStart(sender, e);` and it will work.

Comment: Note also that `Action<object, EventArgs>` is a more appropriate corollary to `EventHandler<EventArgs>` than is `Func<object, EventArgs>`, since the method signature for `EventHandler<EventArgs>` has a `void` return type. Are you sure that your method parameters use `Func<object, EventArgs>`? If so, you can't literally use the syntax I suggested in the previous comment, as the method signature for that delegate type has only a single parameter (of type `object`) and _returns_ a value of type `EventArgs`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that callStart does'nt really need the arguments, so I will try to implement your advices. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It worked! Thank you sir. If you want you can write the answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I offered several suggestions, and I don't know which of them actually helped you. You should write your own answer, stating clearly and specifically what it was you did to solve the problem. You can then click the "accept" checkmark, so that others will be able to easily see that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Peter's suggestions it was fairly easy to solve this problem. First I changed the `Func<Object,EventArg>` argument for an `Action<Object,EventArg>`. Then I changed the event subscription from `OnCall += callStart;` to `OnCall += (sender, e) => callStart(sender, e);`.

In the example of this question the resulting code is:

```
public class1(...., Action<Object,EventArg> callStart){
...
c2 = new class2(..., callStart);
}

public class2(...., Action<Object,EventArg> callStart){
...
c3 = new class3(..., callStart);
}

public class3(...., Action<Object,EventArg> callStart){...

OnCall += (sender, e) => callStart(sender, e);
}
```